# De-selecting a select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox that will select all, at the moment if I press it, it will select all the the options(which is good!), then if I deselect one of them it doesn't deselect the Select All option. Any help in how to do this would be gratefully appreciated.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
<label for="sel1">Select days:</label><br />

<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" /> 
    <label for='all'>Select All</label>
    <ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="moveli">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_1" value="1" /> 
                <label for="box_1">Monday</label>
            </li>
            <li class="moveli">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_2" value="2" /> 
                <label for="box_2">Tuesday</label>
            </li>
            <li class="moveli">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_3" value="3" /> 
                <label for="box_3">Wednesday</label>
            </li>
            <li class="moveli">    
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_4" value="4" /> 
                <label for="box_4">Thursday</label>
            </li>
            <li class="moveli">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_5" value="5" /> 
                <label for="box_5">Friday</label>
            </li>
            <li class="moveli">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_6" value="6" /> 
                <label for="box_6">Saturday</label>
            </li>
            <li class="moveli">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_7" value="7" /> 
                <label for="box_7">Sunday</label>    
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

Script I am currently using to Select All:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="all"],input[name="title"]').bind('click', function(){
        var status = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).parent('li')).prop('checked', status);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function){

}
```

Comment: You're using checkboxes, not radios. The implementation is different. I've amended your question.

Comment: Ah dam, you are right, not sure why I said Radio lol

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid; `li` can only be children of a `ol` and `ul` and a `ul` cannot be a direct descendant of another `ul`. Also, `bind` was deprecated a long while ago. You should be using `on` instead.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I got his code from some other help, I'll look at fixing the HTML and using on. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:
   http://jsfiddle.net/0e018w0y/

You're most of the way there.
I'd attach a "change" event listener to all the checkboxes, confirming that (on change) whether all the checkboxes are selected or not... (FYI you're using checkboxes and not radio buttons.  Radio buttons only allow 1 to be selected at a time.)

```
// On change of any (not "Select All" checkbox)
$('input[name="selected[]"]').change(function () {
    var selectAll = true;
    // Confirm all checkboxes are checked (or not)
    $('input[name="selected[]"]').each(function (i, obj) {
        if ($(obj).is(':checked') === false) {
            // At least one checkbox isn't selected
            selectAll = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    // Update "Select All" checkbox appropriately
    $('input[name="all"]').prop('checked', selectAll);
});
```

In the example I've tried to follow your convention for checking if things are selected or not etc - except I've used "`change()`" rather than "`click()`" (which captures any change event, not just mouse-clicks).

---

Line by line:

```
$('input[name="selected[]"]').change(function () {
   ...
}
```

This captures the change event on all select boxes.  You could use classes or a name convention to identify the checkboxes to attach it to.

```
    var selectAll = true;
```

The scope of this variable reaches the nameless function provided to the `.each(...)` call which follows.  We're using this to track whether every checkbox is checked or not.

```
    $('input[name="selected[]"]').each(function (i, obj) {
        if ($(obj).is(':checked') === false) {
            // At least one checkbox isn't selected
            selectAll = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This checks every checkbox, see if any are *not* checked.

Then we update the "Select All" checkbox appropriately.

---

Looking at it again (2 minutes later), I can see this could be reduced actually:

```
    var allSelected = ($('input[name="selected[]"]:not(:checked)').length === 0);
    // Update "Select All" checkbox appropriately
    $('input[name="all"]').prop('checked', allSelected);
```

I've not tested if this is faster ... I've just offloaded the checking of "is checked" to jQuery itself.  The "`length`" property returns how many elements match the criteria - "`:not(:checked)`" does what you'd expect, matches only the aforementioned inputs which are *not* checked.

If the count is not equal to 0, we deselect the "Select All" checkbox.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zyxgm2kz/

Comment: That is brilliant, worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sean9113 - if you've found an answer you're happy with, don't forget to mark it "accepted" - it helps the system work better :)

Comment: Also mega thanks for breaking down + explaining, really helps

Comment: No problem - pleasure :)  Hope your day went OK!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> You need to bind a `change` listener for all the days `checkbox` and if all the checkboxes are checked then you can play with `select all` checkbox `checked` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var allCB = $('input[name="selected[]"]');
    var mainCB = $('input[name="all"]')
    mainCB.on('click', function () {
        var status = $(this).is(':checked');
        allCB.prop('checked', status);
    });
    allCB.on('change', function () {
        var status = $('input[name="selected[]"]:checked').length === allCB.length;
        $('input[name="all"]').prop('checked', status);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" />
  <label for='all'>Select All</label>
  <ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="moveli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_1" value="1" />
        <label for="box_1">Monday</label>
      </li>
      <li class="moveli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_2" value="2" />
        <label for="box_2">Tuesday</label>
      </li>
      <li class="moveli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_3" value="3" />
        <label for="box_3">Wednesday</label>
      </li>
      <li class="moveli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_4" value="4" />
        <label for="box_4">Thursday</label>
      </li>
      <li class="moveli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_5" value="5" />
        <label for="box_5">Friday</label>
      </li>
      <li class="moveli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_6" value="6" />
        <label for="box_6">Saturday</label>
      </li>
      <li class="moveli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="box_7" value="7" />
        <label for="box_7">Sunday</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="all"],input[name="title').click(function(event) {  //on click 
        if(this.checked) { 
            $('input[type="checkbox').each(function() { 
                this.checked = true; 
            });
        }else{
            $('.input[type="checkbox').each(function() { 
                this.checked = false; 
            });         
        }
    });

});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/3kqoq1ge/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="all"],input[name="title"]').bind('click', function () {
    var status = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).parent('li')).prop('checked', status);
});

var checkbox = $(':checkbox').not('#all');
$(checkbox).change(function () {
    checkbox.each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        } else {
            $(':checkbox#all').prop('checked', false)
        }


    })

})
```

Get the checkbox except the all then check if one is uncheck remove the check from all

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3kqoq1ge/2/)